# Trouble passing JavaScript variable to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables

The solution to my problem now seems very basic. Although I understood php runs server-side I didn't know that that the php ran on pageload even if the include was nestled in the ajax callback. Although I could display the query results by returning the php in the javascript value attribute, if I didn't include the reference to the php script I got unterminated string errors.  What I now realize is that (I think) the include caused the php to run before the ajax was fired  which is why the php squawked about an undefined index. Hard coding an ID into php would run fine since it didn't need anything from ajax to run the query. Removing the include in the callback caused an undefined literal error because, having nothing to reference, the php broke causing the parser to see .value = " which is literally unterminated. By removing the php include and returning the query results via JSON, everything works perfectly. Seemed my road block was being stuck at how I learned to return php data to html. Anyway, valuable and useful lesson learned...

The application is to pull log data, make modifications and save as a new or updated log file. The ajax sends an ID to the php script for the query to get the old info and populate each row cell. The second cell (act-col) is dynamically loaded based on the selection in the first cell (reg-col). To allow the user the ability to not only see the old info but also make changes, a second ajax call to get the right options is made. Anything already there is then emptied out and the new options are loaded. This also makes sure that the select box is defined since, initially, until something is put in the the reg-col cell, the act-col cell is basically an empty box. After that the rest of the cells are loaded with the old info, a new row is created and it loops through until all the info is displayed.  Putting the add row function at the bottom of loop causes an extra row to be added but when the loop is completed I found that using javascript to delete it actually triggers all the math functions that occur as if the user creates a log from scratch. Probably not the best solution but prevents having to pull data from another table to populate those fields on the initial button click.

Now that I understand it better I can clearly see all the suggestions pointing me to this. Oh, well...not the first time and surely not the last that hind site has humbled (and humiliated) me. Here's what finally worked:

Here's the javascript/jquery:

```
$(function(){
            $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                   url: 'phpScripts/lastSession.php',
              dataType: 'json',
                  data: {'id': pt_id},
                 cache:false,
               success:function(data){

        for(var j=0; j<data.length; j++){            

                    var reg=data[j].region;
                    $(".reg-col:eq("+j+")").val(reg);

                        if ((reg)==="knee/hip"){  $(function(){ $.ajax({
                                    url: 'phpScripts/getKneeHip.php',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    cache:false,
                                    async:false,
                                    success: function (json) {
                                        $(".act-col:eq("+j+")").empty().end();
                                        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                                            $('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value).appendTo( $(".act-col:eq("+j+")"));

                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }//end if

                        else if ((reg)=="shoulder"){  $(function() { $.ajax({
                                    url: 'phpScripts/getShoulder.php',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    cache:false,
                                    async:false,
                                    success: function (json) {
                                        $(".act-col:eq("+j+")").empty().end()
                                        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                                            $('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value).appendTo( $(".act-col:eq("+j+")"));

                                        })
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        }//end if

                                            $(".act-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].activity);
                                            $(".reps-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].reps);
                                                   $(".weight-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].weights);
                                                   $(".prps-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].purposes);
                                                   $(".time-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].time);
                                                   $(".type-col:eq("+j+")").val(data[j].type);

                        addRow('dataTable');

          }
        document.getElementsByName("chk[]")[j].checked=true;
        document.getElementById('deleteBtn').click();
```

Here's the php:

```
      $ID = $_POST['id'];
  $return = array(); 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history WHERE patient_id = '$ID' AND date_of_service IN (SELECT MAX(date_of_service) FROM history WHERE patient_id = $ID)"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
array_push($return,array('region'=>$row['region'],'activity'=>$row['exercise'], 'reps'=>$row['reps'], 'weights'=>$row['weight'], 'purposes'=>$row['purpose'], 'time'=>$row['time'], 'type'=>$row['type'])); 
 } 
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: No. The `$ID= @$_POST['id'];` is NOT in `interest of simplicity and preventing an undefined index error` - it is just lazy and lame. Do things right - all you need is just `isset()` and ternary operator (or a function if need to do this more often

Comment: plus to webnet. @ is a suppressor. A costly one at that. isset($_POST['id']) in conditional would be the ideal way to wrap that... ps, since someone will yell at you, switch to PDO or mysqli

Comment: In regards to the "isset"...I left it off so the code will execute. Since nothing is being passed in, isset will be returned false and all will stop because it will throw an error. If I select a default it will return the default. It's not a matter of being lazy, it's a matter of trying to find out the problem. I realize a is a suppressor and I put it there so the notices wouldn't halt the script.

Comment: In regards to the Msql, Mysqli, PDO, I adressed that in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute a server-side script `phpScripts/lastSession.php` on the client, which obviously isn't going to work. I'm not entirely clear on what you want to have happen there, but it seems like you would want that script to execute as part of your ajax call.

Comment: Ultranaut is right and as you can see the url parameter of the ajax call is the file you're trying to include. So what's the goal here? It looks like you should be either redirecting to another page or returning json data in the success method, then writing as you desire. Whatever is going on here is definitely not going to work unless the contents of that include only write out javascript and is parsed on page load... even if it did manage to write the js correctly, this is a bad way to do it for sure.

Comment: In regards to the "isset"...I left it off so the code will execute. Since nothing is being passed in, isset will be returned false and all will stop because it will throw an error. If I select a default it will return the default. It's not a matter of being lazy, it's a matter of trying to find out the problem. I realize a is a suppressor and I put it there so I wouldn't have to have the notices crash it.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I should have been clearer. The script returns query results that will be psoted as a value in a table like so:  document.getElementsByName("exercises[]")[i].value ="<?php  echo $row_last['exercise']; ?>"; This works fine. The problem I have is getting the ajax output id='2360' to show up in $ID=$_POST['id']; so the query will return data related to that $ID only.

Comment: That's all good and well, but the point is that you can't execute php code on the client, i.e. in the browser, which is where your javascript is getting executed. The two things happen at different times, in different places.

Comment: why then, does it execute then when I type a number in the pghp script? the php isn't executing on the browser, it's executing in the php script. The results are returned to the javascript code like this this:document.getElementsByName("exercises[]")[i].value ="<?php echo $row_last['exercise']; ?>";

Comment: Do you have this up somewhere accessible?

Comment: Sorry, ultranut, local host only. Edited the post, though, to isolate the problem as my original was misleading. For now, it seems like my issue is related to ajax or the php script it calls (or something just plain stupid that I'm missing...)

Comment: Still struggling to understand the issue here. The application is to populate all the data from a previous visit so the user can make any adjustments and resave as a new encounter. Everything works as expected, just can't pass the user ID to the php query. If I do sometheing like:if(isset($ID)){
 $ID=$_POST['id'];
}else{
 $ID = '2360';
}
echo $ID;

Comment: (continuation of above...)all runs well for he user with ID 2360. Is there a way to re-trigger the php with the button click that initiates the ajax call? Appears I need to include php script that does the query to the page where the query results are returned or I get an unterminated string error.

Comment: Well, the hammer to the head that made me see how dumb I am didn't hurt as much as banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out but the shame that comes with it is much worse. Instead of searching for a solution that wouldn't work I should have taken the cues from @ultranut and Kai Quing. Now seems like a no brainer to send the variable to php, run the query and return the results using JSON...guess I was blinded by Dreamweaver server behaviors. Apologies to you guys. I'll be sure to post the solution when I finish this last piece of humble pie.